# Mule Dynamic flow name runtime

Tags: mule

I was wondering whether anyone had any experience dynamically setting the name of the flow I want to redirect to in Mule? The use case is that I might have data coming in and I want to route the request to a specific flow based on the data coming in. However, the mule-config may not know of this flow until runtime, so I need to select a flow that corresponds to the data in a certain incoming field.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a destination flow is usually done by sending a message to the inbound endpoint of the desired flow.

For example, if you use VM inbound endpoints in your different flows, you can then at runtime use a dynamic VM outbound endpoint that will target the right VM inbound endpoint.